# Is it possible to change the root location of the new relic config file?

Tags: javascript, config, newrelic

currently my config file lives at the root called `newrelic.js`

I would like it to live under `config/newrelic.js`

I cant find any docs on this and feel like if I change it's location it wont be picked up?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Use the NEW_RELIC_HOME environment variable to set the path.

New Relic documentation here:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration